# What does $\iff$ mean?

Tags: logic, notation

What does $\iff$ mean?

[Here](https://github.com/ethereum/research/raw/master/papers/CasperTFG/CasperTFG.pdf)'s the context of where I saw the notation (p. $5, 2.3$):

$$m \in L(v, M) \iff \not \exists m' \in D(M) \text{ such that } V(m')=v \text{ and } m' \succ m$$

It looks like a two-way mapping, but I just want to clarify (I'll check with the author as well).

Comment: See [List of logic symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols).

Comment: I don't understand why my question has been marked as unclear. It is clear enough to me. I've got an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means "if and only if".

$$A \iff B$$

means $A$ implies $B$ and $B$ implies $A$.

Comment: I found another answer as well [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols#Symbols_that_point_left_or_right).